# VS2015 XAML Universal Windows app Pages

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am writing a small Universal Windows app (primarily for Windows 10IoT, but would be fun to have it also running on a desktop).
This app has 2 pages. 1 MainPage and one SettingsPage.
How can i switch to the SettingsPage and back again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch pages by using the navigation methods on the [`Frame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame) object.

To go to the settings page:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
```

To go back:

```
this.Frame.GoBack();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thought this was more complicated than that